# Digital Forensic - media sterilise

Tags: media, data-cleaning, computer-forensics

I am done with my media and i have sterilise my media using sterilise. I just want to check if anyone know of any test/ways/procedure to confirmed that the media is sterilised.

Thanks

Regards
J

Comment: Which program are you using? I'm not familiar with "sterilise."  Also, to answer your question we need to know what type of media you're using. For example, certain flash media may retain copies of data in "wear-leveled" areas of the device, but spinning disks usually don't.

Comment: I find disks become unreadable if I overwrite the entire disk with zeros, break off all the PCB I can see with a screwdriver, pop them in a plastic bag in the freezer for a month, then boil them for an hour in water and drill through them in a couple of places before smashing the heck out of them with a sledgehammer. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Windows 8, you can do:

```
Format H: /P:7
```

I also like Eraser, allows you to wipe unused disk space and schedule.

https://eraser.heidi.ie/

Apparently it's hard to use tools like this on SSDs because of wear-leveling. DBAN won't work for full drive wipes, you need to use the built in erase commands. However, Windows implements TRIM and UNMAP which should securely garbage collect on SSDs.

https://www.howtogeek.com/257196/how-to-check-if-trim-is-enabled-for-your-ssd-and-enable-it-if-it-isnt/

Answer (score 0):

If you sterilize the media by writing 0s across the whole drive, you can run a checksum 64 or checksum 32 on it to verify that it is in fact sterilized. The result will return all 0s. This only works if you're writing 0s across the whole media.